# C# - Datagridview compare two cells value and set style

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to write code in `DataGridView` event `CellFormatting` to trigger the logic that compares if column ( `qty` and `scanqty` ) values in same row are different, then set background color to Yellow. But occur runtime error

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

Below is my sample code, anyone can help me, thank you very much.

```
private void dgProductList_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dgProductList.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "scanqty")
    {
        var sqty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value.ToString()) ? 0 : int.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        var qty = int.Parse(dgProductList[e.RowIndex, 1].Value.ToString());

        if (sqty != qty)
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when using the `[ ]` operator to access data in the `DataGridView` the syntax is :

```
dgProductList[columnIndex, rowIndex]
```

[image]
your are doing it the reverse way. please change this line:

```
var qty = int.Parse(dgProductList[e.RowIndex, 1].Value.ToString());
```

to this:

```
var qty = int.Parse(dgProductList[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
```

another possibility could be to use the column name `qty`

```
var qty = int.Parse(dgProductList["qty", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: no problem. Best way to say thank you on StackOverflow is to mark the answer as accepted. If you don't know how to do it, here is [a post that explains it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Wish you a good day

Answer (score 1):

Consider something like this, for performance reasons:

```
private void dgProductList_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == COL_INDEX_OF_SCANQTY_COLUMN)
    {
        var sqty = (DATATYPE_OF_SCANQTY)e.Value;
        var qty = (DATATYPE_OF_QTY)dgProductList[1, e.RowIndex].Value;

        if (sqty != qty)
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need to round trip from string and back to int etc. Also you are happy to hard code that QTY is always column 1 but you look up the name of the column for scanqty and compare it to string to check if it's the scanqty column - you might as well hard code that too

If you don't know the datatypes of the values, pause it in the debugger and take a look..

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers may be correct, I think the real problem here is that `e.RowIndex` and `e.ColumnIndex` can be -1 (e.g. for the header row). So you have to check if these indices are `>= 0` first and ignore those with -1.

```
private void dgProductList_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && this.dgProductList.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "scanqty")
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I misunderstood the first data row index is 0 and first column index is 0